# Running multiple instances of same app, each on different port using same jetty

Tags: jetty

Is it possible to run two instances of an application on different port using same jetty installation? If possible, Can any one suggest/guide me? Or may be share some good documentation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using what techniques? Standalone `jetty-home`? or `embedded-jetty`?

Comment: Hi Joakim, Its standalone. One war file is already deployed on Jetty and running on a given port. I have a updated war file of same application and I want to run on same jetty on a different port. Not sure if it possible.

Comment: It is possible, in either a single JVM, or two.